# XY trajectory plot using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

I am trying to plot a trajectory in real-time using Javascript and Highcharts. The data will come from external sensors but for the moment I was practicing with this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0fp1gzw8/1/

As you can see, the JS snippet tries to plot a circle using a cosine and a sine function:

```
load: function () {

  var series = this.series[0];

  setInterval(function () {

    a = a + 0.1;
    x = Math.sin(a),
    y = Math.cos(a);

    series.addPoint([x, y], true);

  }, 100);
}
```

The problem is that once the point has crossed the x axes, the line segment is no more drawn between two consecutive samples, instead it connects the new sample with one of the old ones already plotted before:

[image]

How can I solve this and get a clean x-y plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts expects spline/line chart data to always be sorted by the x value.  With this expectation, when you call `addPoint` it looks like it draws the line segment to the previous x-value not the previously added point.

If you [switch your code](http://jsfiddle.net/0fp1gzw8/2/) to use `setData`:

```
var data = [];
var series = this.series[0];
setInterval(function () {
  a = a + 0.1;
  x = Math.sin(a),
  y = Math.cos(a);
  data.push([x,y]);
  series.setData(data, true);
}, 100);
```

it draws the line segments correctly but you get lots of these errors in the console:

```
Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15
```

You might have better luck switching to a [scatter chart](http://jsfiddle.net/0fp1gzw8/3/) that doesn't have this limitation.  If you need the line segments, you could add them yourself with the [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried several JS chart libraries but it seems to me that the vast majority of them just focus on plotting dynamic, real-time values as simple time-series sorted on the x axes just as you said. What I want to do is very simple and yet I am losing a lot of time on that. Do you know any JS library that may fit my needs (dynamic chart, pure x-y plot, some control on axis params, acceptable performances) and that does not need hacky things to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Just a note for scatter: you can set `lineWidth: 1` and scatter will connect points: http://jsfiddle.net/0fp1gzw8/4/